# I am using a SeaDAC Lite to send pulses to a PC and need a C# solution to capture the input

Tags: c#, usb

I have the box powered up and it appears correctly in the device manager but I am unsure of how to capture the input.
This is being used instead of a card plugged into the server so that an application can be run on a small factor box.

Does anyone know how to code something in c# so I can capture the input from the USB connection?

Comment: In device manager what is the name of the device.  USB devices are sometimes serial ports and just use the serial port name like Com3:.  What driver is installed.  Is it a vendor or standard microsoft driver?  Does vendor have a driver?  The interface to the device depends on the driver that is installed.

Comment: The device shows in device manager as "SeaDAC Lite DIO-8". The device properties status has it as working properly. The device driver is from SeaLevel systems and has been updated to the latest version. The thing is that I do not know how to code something that will show what is coming from the USB so I can hook this into the application that needs it.

Comment: See manual : https://www.sealevel.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Talos-Framework-Manual.pdf

Comment: Thanks jdweng that Talos code looks like a good place to start.